# Can I add a git release as a submodule?

Tags: git, tags, release, git-submodules

I have binary files in a github release tag, which I think is not cloneable. In another git repo I'd like to add these binary files (they are like dependencies) as a submodule, so that they can get updated easily. I dont want to submit binaries to the first repository if possible.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, git releases are completely separate from a regular git repo, so your other git repo cannot directly reference them.

All you could do is version a script able to get the releases from the first repo at the right tag, using the [GitHub API for Releases](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/).